# What is the difference between subscribe() and subscribeWith() in RxJava2 in android?

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java2

What is the difference between `subscribe()` and `subscribeWith()` in RxJava2 in android? Both function are used to subscribe an Observer on an Observable. What is the major difference between the two function ?.
Where to use subscribe and where to use subscribeWith. If possible please provide code samples.

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0?

Comment: Yes i have read the documentation and i understand that they have introduced the concept of Disposable. I would just like a simple and easier to understand explanation.

Comment: It literally says: _"Due to the Reactive-Streams specification, `Publisher.subscribe` returns void and the pattern by itself no longer works in 2.0. To remedy this, the method `E subscribeWith(E subscriber)` has been added to each base reactive class which returns its input subscriber/observer as is."_ That exactly answers your question. What part of that don't you understand?

Answer (score 7):

> Since 1.x `Observable.subscribe(Subscriber)` returned `Subscription`, users often added the `Subscription` to a `CompositeSubscription` for example:
>
> ```
> CompositeSubscription composite = new CompositeSubscription();
>
> composite.add(Observable.range(1, 5).subscribe(new TestSubscriber<Integer>()));
> ```
>
> Due to the Reactive-Streams specification, `Publisher.subscribe` returns void and the pattern by itself no longer works in 2.0. To remedy this, the method E `subscribeWith`(E subscriber) has been added to each base reactive class which returns its input subscriber/observer as is. With the two examples before, the 2.x code can now look like this since `ResourceSubscriber` implements `Disposable` directly:
>
> ```
> CompositeDisposable composite2 = new CompositeDisposable();
>
> composite2.add(Flowable.range(1, 5).subscribeWith(subscriber));
> ```

Source: [What's different in [RxJava] 2.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#subscriber)

Comment: Basically understand this, but what's with the sudden unexplained appearance of `ResourceSubscriber`? Are you saying that in your example, the `subscriber` in `.subscribeWith(subscriber)` must be a `ResourceSubscriber`?